# How to convert a matrix of strings into matrix of 0 and 1's

Tags: r, matrix, reshape2

Hi  I have a dataset which looks like this

```
name1  a b c d  
name2  a c e g i  
name3  t j i m n z
```

`dput` output:

```
structure(c("name1", "name2", "name3", "a ", "a", "r ", "b", "c", "k ", "c", "e", "l", "d", "t", "o", "e", "j", "m", "", "k", "n"), .Dim = c(3L, 7L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("V1", "V2", "V3", "V4", "V5", "V6", "V7")))
```

I want to convert to matrix like this

```
         a b c d e g i j m n t z
name1    1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
name2    1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 
name3    0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

How can I do this in R?

Comment: are the `name`s rownames or a column?

Comment: names are rownames and column names come from combining all the values present in the dataset

Comment: I meant for the original data.   It essentially amounts to what @Joran said.   This is the very doable, but the approach depends on the structure of your original data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
## Assuming this is your starting data
dat <- read.table(text="name1  a b c d  NA NA\nname2  a c e g i NA\nname3  t j i m n z")
rownames(dat) <- dat$V1 
dat$V1 <- NULL
```

I'm assuming your data is something like above.

---

```
## store the rownames
NM <- rownames(dat)  # or NM <- c("name1", "name2", "name3")

## IMPORTANT. Make sure you have characters, not factors. 
dat <- sapply(dat, as.character)

cols <- sort(unique(as.character(unlist(dat))))

results <- sapply(cols, function(cl) apply(dat, 1, `%in%`, x=cl))
results[] <- as.numeric(results)

rownames(results) <- NM

results

      a b c d e g i j m n t z
name1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
name2 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0
name3 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

Comment: 10521402_C_T a
10521502_A_T b
10521576_G_A c
10521624_G_A d
10521769_G_T e
10521798_T_A f
10521913_C_T a
10523162_T_C b
10523562_C_T a
10527303_T_C t
10529333_C_A h
10529384_G_C f
10529384_G_C a
10527303_T_C b | the table looks like this.            Hi I am really for confused how to go form this step. Since it contains duplicate rows and I need to show them as one row having two ones for two different column. Can you please look at it and let me know any suggestion for this.

Comment: Hi @dissw.geek9.  It is very hard to read code in the comments.  If you have a follow up question, it is perfectly alright to open up a new question and simply state that it is in response or follow up to this one.  (at the bottom of your original question there is a "share" button which you can use to link back to this question)

Comment: Hi Thanks for replyting back.I found a way to get the solution for the problem I was facing.

Comment: @RicardoSaporta, I know this is OLD, but you might be interested in [the benchmarks in my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20689146/1270695). Fun stuff!

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way:

```
qw = function(s) unlist(strsplit(s,'[[:blank:]]+'))
name1 <- qw("a b c d")
name2 <- qw("a c e g i")
name3 <- qw("t j i m n z")

rows <- qw("name1 name2 name3")
cols <- sort(unique(c(name1,name2,name3)))

nr <- length(rows)
nc <- length(cols)

outmat <- matrix(0,nr,nc,dimnames=list(rows,cols))

for (i in rows){
    outmat[i,get(i)] <- 1
}

#       a b c d e g i j m n t z
# name1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
# name2 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0
# name3 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

The function `qw` is not really necessary, but made it easier to read in your example.

Comment: for reading in text, you can simply use `read.table(text=..)`.  It will automatically splice columns on white space

Answer (score 1):

### Update: A much faster alternative

You'll get the best speed by using matrix indexing. Here's an example (with comments, so you can see what's going on).

```
## Assuming this is your starting data
dat <- read.table(text="name1  a b c d  NA NA\nname2  a c e g i NA\nname3  t j i m n z")
rownames(dat) <- dat$V1 
dat$V1 <- NULL

## Convert the data.frame into a single character vector
A <- unlist(lapply(dat, as.character), use.names = FALSE)

## Identify the unique levels
levs <- sort(unique(na.omit(A)))

## Get the index position for the Row/Column combination
##   that needs to be recoded as "1"
Rows <- rep(sequence(nrow(dat)), ncol(dat))
Cols <- match(A, levs)

## Create an empty matrix
m <- matrix(0, nrow = nrow(dat), ncol = length(levs),
            dimnames = list(rownames(dat), levs))

## Use matrix indexing to replalce the relevant values with 1
m[cbind(Rows, Cols)] <- 1L
m
#       a b c d e g i j m n t z
# name1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
# name2 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0
# name3 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

---

### The benchmarks

I benchmarked Ricardo's answer, my `data.table` answer, and the matrix indexing answer after creating a 30000 row version of the initial `data.frame`. Here are the results:

```
dat2 <- dat ## A backup
dat <- do.call(rbind, replicate(10000, dat, simplify = FALSE))
dim(dat)
# [1] 30000     6

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(AM(), AMDT(), RS(), times = 10)
# Unit: milliseconds
#    expr        min         lq     median        uq       max neval
#    AM()   44.30915   56.21873   57.95815   86.1518  265.3053    10
#  AMDT()  231.71928  245.64236  291.19601  376.8983  515.8216    10
#    RS() 4414.01127 4698.47293 4731.72877 5484.6185 5726.8092    10
```

Matrix indexing clearly wins, but given the brevity of the `data.table` syntax to get the job done, I'd much prefer that approach! Nice work @Arun in porting Hadley's work with "reshape2" to `data.table`!!!

---

#### Original answer

Here's a "data.table" alternative. It requires at least version 1.8.11 of "data.table".

#### load required packages

```
library(data.table)
library(reshape2)
packageVersion("data.table")
# [1] ‘1.8.11’
```

#### `melt` and `cast` your `data.table`

```
DT <- data.table(dat, keep.rownames=TRUE)
dcast.data.table(melt(DT, id.vars="rn"), rn ~ value)
# Aggregate function missing, defaulting to 'length'
#       rn NA a b c d e g i j m n t z
# 1: name1  0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
# 2: name2  0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0
# 3: name3  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1
```